# How do the steps of this definite integral work?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Sorry if this is a really basic question but I can't seem to get my head around the steps involved in this integration at all. My equation to be integrated is as follows:

${ds \over s}=\mu dt$

Integrating between $t=0$ and $t=T$ supposedly yields the following:

$s(T) = s(0)e^{\mu T}$

What are the intermediate steps to get here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking the indefinite integral of both sides instead:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ds}{s} &= \mu \, dt \\
\int \frac{1}{s} \, ds &= \int \mu \, dt \\
\ln|s| &= \mu t + C &\text{for some constant $C \in \mathbb R$}\\
e^{\ln|s|} &= e^{\mu t + C}\\
|s| &= e^{\mu t} \cdot e^C \\
s &= \underbrace{(\pm e^C)}_{A}e^{\mu t} \\
s(t) &= Ae^{\mu t} &\text{for some constant $A \in \mathbb R$}\\
\end{align*}
To solve for $A$, notice that if we substitute $t = 0$, then we get:
$$
s(0) = Ae^{\mu \cdot 0} = A \cdot 1 = A
$$
Hence, by taking $t = T$, we conclude that:
$$
s(T) = s(0)e^{\mu T}
$$